# Exporting CloudWatch logs to S3 bucket issues

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Im trying to use the aws console to export the logs of my application to an S3 bucket.

I followed the steps on this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html

But the task only creates aws-logs-write-test file in each task executed.

[image]

Have anyone faced this issue?

I will also attach some info while im creating the task

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try without stream prefix.

Comment: Thank you! this worked. I can't exactly know why, but worked.

Comment: PS. Stream prefix is used for *filtering* log stream with name prefix.

Comment: Is the "aws-logs-write-test" file part of the normal behaviour of the export task?